# How to erase or bypass remote management to become an administrator

Tags: macbook-pro

I traded computers and received MacBook pro 2019 and initially I was a admin I made the mistake of erasing everything when I lost my password and now when I boot it says remote management  (Genesis telecommunications laboratory ) please provide shorthand name and password. It won't allow me to do anything and pops up continuously I just want to bypass or learn how to erase and start without. How do I get past it